# Qual è il significato di "puntina" in questo testo?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Lipari li 8 Novembre 1856 
>   Ho caricato col nome di Dio a buon salvamento una volta tanto in questo porto di Sotto il Monastero per conto e rischio del signor Ferlazzo Onofrio sopra e sotto coperta della sua Nominata San 
>   Cristoforo al comando di Bartolomeo Barbuto per condurre e consegnare 
>   in questo suo presente viaggio in Cefalù le appiè nominate, e numerate mercanzie sciutte, intiere, e ben condizionate, segnate come di contro, 
>   
>   e così promette detto Capitano al suo salvo arrivo consegnarle al Signor Michelangelo Di Paola e di nolo gli sarà pagato secondo contratto 
>   
>   e per fede del vero sarà questa con altre simili firmata da detto Capitano e non sapendo egli scrivere, per lui da terza persona ed una compita le altre restino di niun valore. 
>   
>   C. 1428. Dico Cantàra mille quattrocento ventotto pietra pomice 
>   S. 175. Dico Salme cento settanta cinque vino malvasìa 
>   
>   N. 7. Dico Numero sette barili di càpperi salati **qualità puntina**.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "qualità puntina" in questa lettera? Ho cercato alle voce "punto" e "punta" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Comment: Puntina si riferisce ad una varietà di capperi. Appena possibile cerco di scrivere una risposta più articolata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il termine puntina indica una particolare [qualità di cappero](https://www.bibenda.it/news_bibenda_singola.php?id=1063).

> In Italia il Cappero si trova un po’ ovunque, dalla Liguria all’isola
>   di Salina; ma la qualità pantesca resta insuperata; per disciplinare
>   qui si coltiva in aridocoltura solo la cultivar Nocellara varietà
>   Inermis (senza spine), **la cui selezione più alta è rappresentata da
>   Puntine** o Occhi di pernice e Lacrimedde, con diametro massimo di 7
>   millimetri, mentre i più grandi si chiamano Mezzanelli, Mezzani e
>   Capperoni. Seppure industrializzata, risulta di buon livello anche la
>   produzione del Midi francese e della Spagna, mentre Marocco (primo
>   paese produttore), Turchia e Cipro, si segnalano per produzioni su
>   vasta scala